# Should I be using tf.keras or keras in 2020?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

A while back I read this [post on PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/) and was satisfied enough to switch completely to `tf.keras`.

But since then I noticed the [Keras website](https://keras.io/) got an overhaul and seems to be expanding on its ambitions.

So I'm a bit confused.

- Is it still true that *"the latest release of the keras package (v2.3.0) will be the last release to support multiple backends and feature updates. Moving forward, the keras package will receive only bug fixes."* from [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/)?
- If I stick with `tf.keras` could I miss out on anything? I'm talking about specific features (to make this a "fact based" question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [answer on the Datascience Stack Exchange site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/60408) seems to answer this question.

François Chollet, the creator of Keras, recommends that users switch to `tf.keras` ([source](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19))

> New release of multi-backend Keras: 2.3.0
>
> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0
>
> - First release of multi-backend Keras with full TF 2 support
> - Continued support for Theano/CNTK
> - Will be the last major release of multi-backend Keras
>
> We recommend you switch your Keras code to tf.keras.

And in two replies:

> Both Theano and CNTK are out of development. Meanwhile, as Keras backends they represent less than 4% of Keras usage. The other 96% of users (of which more than half are already on tf.keras) are better served with tf.keras.
>
> Keras development will focus on tf.keras going forward.

> Importantly, we will seek to start developing tf.keras in its own standalone GitHub repository at keras-team/keras in order to make it much easier for 3rd party folks to contribute.
>
> Keras has never been moving faster than now :)