# Issues with TensorFlow and Keras in-term of Keras optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

currently I am learning the basics of chatbot programming and have little or none experience with TensorFlow and Keras. while coding my program I came upon an error message :
**AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'TFOptimizer'**
Version
: Tensorflow 2.1.0
: keras 2.3.1
: Python 3.7

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import json
import pickle
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import TFOptimizer



import numpy as np
np.array(object, dtype=object, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Lambda

import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
import random
words=[]
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?', '!']
data_file = open('intents.json' , encoding='utf-8').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)
```

Problem :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))
sgd = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy']) 
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)
print("model created")
```

Error Messages :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-54920be00d53> in <module>
     12 #fitting and saving the model
     13 hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
---> 14 model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)
     15 print("model created")

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1150             raise NotImplementedError
   1151         from ..models import save_model
-> 1152         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
   1153 
   1154     @saving.allow_write_to_gcs

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in save_wrapper(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
    447                 os.remove(tmp_filepath)
    448         else:
--> 449             save_function(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
    450 
    451     return save_wrapper

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    539                 return
    540         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='w') as h5dict:
--> 541             _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
    542     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
    543         # write as binary stream

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
    161             layer_group[name] = val
    162     if include_optimizer and model.optimizer:
--> 163         if isinstance(model.optimizer, optimizers.TFOptimizer):
    164             warnings.warn(
    165                 'TensorFlow optimizers do not '

AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'TFOptimizer'
```

Comment: Just remove the line?

Comment: Do not mix `keras` and `tf.keras`. Stick to `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keras` and `tensorflow.keras` are two different implementations of the Keras API and as such should not be mixed. [According to the creator of the Keras API](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19), users should prefer the `tensorflow.keras` implementation going forward.

> New release of multi-backend Keras: 2.3.0
>
> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0
>
> - First release of multi-backend Keras with full TF 2 support
> - Continued support for Theano/CNTK
> - Will be the last major release of multi-backend Keras
>
> We recommend you switch your Keras code to tf.keras.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377877/5666087 for more information.